# Why having even number of edges in cut imply $\mathcal{B}(G) \subset \mathcal{C}^\perp(G)$ and $\mathcal{C}(G)\subset\mathcal{B}^\perp(G)$?

Tags: graph-theory

$\mathcal{C}(G)$ is cut space. $\mathcal{B}(G)$ is cut space.

Diestel say at [theorem 1.9.4](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch1.pdf), having even number of edges in cut mply $\mathcal{B}(G) \subset \mathcal{C}^\perp(G)$ and $\mathcal{C}(G)\subset\mathcal{B}^\perp(G)$.

Why?

If F and F' have even number of edges in common, $\langle F,F'\rangle =0$. 
So, $\mathcal{B}(G) , \mathcal{C}^\perp(G) , \mathcal{C}(G) , \mathcal{B}^\perp(G)$ should be related each other. But it's not clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offence but it looks like you are rushing through Diestel (this is your third question on it in 1 or 2 days). It is a very good introduction book, but you need to take the time to understand everything, otherwise you won't get much from it.

In this question, you saw the important part : $\langle F,F'\rangle=0$ **if and only if** $F$ and $F'$ have an even number of common edges.

You have the definition, for any subspace $\mathcal{F}$ of the edge space $\mathcal{E}(G)$,
$$ \mathcal{F}^\perp := \left\{ D\in\mathcal{E}(G) \ \mid \ \langle F,D\rangle=0\text{ for all }F\in\mathcal{F}\right\}$$
And you also know that any cycle $C\in\mathcal{C}$ has an even number of edges in any cut $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

You are asked to prove first that these implie $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{C}^\perp$. You need to "break down" this statement. What do you need to prove ?

> $\forall B\in \mathcal{B},\ B\in \mathcal{C}^\perp$

Which can be written

> $\forall B\in \mathcal{B},\ \forall C\in \mathcal{C},\ \langle C,B\rangle=0$

Is this true? If so, can you write the other statement in a similar fashion?

Hope this helps and that you are enjoying the Diestel.